# Spring application-context.xml --- java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd

Tags: java, xml, spring, facebook, spring-mvc

I am new with spring social, I am creating an application that will interact with facebook and twitter. I have already did the twitter part by using twitter4j but for facebook I am trying to use spring facebook but i am having a hard time using it with this exceptions.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
12:47:39.612 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:facebook="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.7.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd">


    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.poc.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg value="test" />
    </bean>
    <mongo:repositories base-package="org.poc.repository" />

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>

    <facebook:config app-id="${facebook.app.id}" app-secret="${facebook.app.secret}"/>

    <!-- <bean name="personService" class="org.poc.service.PersonRecordServiceImpl" />  -->
     <bean name="twitterApp" class="org.poc.twitter.TwitterApp" />  
 <bean name="twitterService" class="org.poc.service.TwitterServiceImpl" />  
</beans>
```

Comment: Do you have `org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook` in your CLASSPATH?

Comment: In case this Facebook sample app might be of any help: https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-boot-security-social-sample

Comment: yes Karthikeyan Vaithilingam i have it in my classpath:

Comment: thanks sanjay will give a try.

Comment: The duplicate is basically the same question, however it arose from a not suitable solution for the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, actually i was using the wrong spring dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

but the correct dependency for spring facebook is.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems the facebook schema is not available anymore or removed, 
Keep a local xsd file and refer it in your context like mentioned here 
 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/issues/79

Create a folder xml inside your classpath (src/main/) folder and add a xsd file as spring-social-facebook-1.1.xsd with content below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    targetNamespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook">

    <xsd:element name="config">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="app-id" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="app-secret" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="app-namespace" use="optional" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

and in your applicationContext.xml, refer this XSD

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook classpath:xml/spring-social-facebook-1.1.xsd
```

Comment: I tried this but now I get **"Could not resolve XML entity [classpath:/xml/spring-social-facebook-1.1.xsd] against system root URL java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath"** ... I am using 4.0.1.

Comment: What' s your spring beans xsd version ? For me it works xmlns:facebook="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook classpath:test.xsd"

Comment: i am using spring-beans-3.0.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the xsd isn't present at that URL. Spring uses a custom resolver for xsd files and always tries to load them from the included jar files (the same applies for all other xsd files). So it is either a matter of the wrong version (or not at all) of spring-social-facebook or using incompatible spring and spring social versions. Spring uses the `spring.schemas` and `spring.handlers` files in the `META-INF` directories to determine from where to load what.